# Printing the documents based on document type in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have .doc,.xls,.PPt,.rtf files in the server. How do i implement the print functionality for the user. I have the list of file names and file type. Please suggest some code samples to print the documents based on the file type. I am using c# 4.0 ASP.NET .thanks.

Regards,
jebli.

Comment: what do you mean with `print`? are you really aware of the difference between server- and client-side?

Comment: :) yes. I need to read a document that is saved in the server. The client must be able to read the document and print it in his default printer.

Answer (score 1):

Using code like the next, you can print most files:

```
ProcessStartInfo inf = new ProcessStartInfo();
inf.FileName = FileName;  // the full path to the file you want to print
inf.Verb = "print";
Process.Start(inf);
```

**BUT:**

- You need to have a program installed locally that handles the printing
- The print is done locally
- "Local" means "on the server"!

Comment: i need to print the in the document in the client machine .